# New chain for specific IP iptables

Tags: iptables

I need to create a new chain to treat a specific IP, say 192.168.0.101.

In this new chain, this IP will have access to all services, except FTP.

My solution is:

```
iptables -N IP1

iptables -A IP1 -p tcp --dport 20 -j DROP
iptables -A IP1 -p tcp --dport 21 -j DROP
iptables -A IP1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.101 -j IP1
```

Is the solution correct? Does two rules with --sport 20, 21 are required for incoming packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggested rules should work, but there may be cases where a DROP in a chain is not the correct action.

For example if you wanted some later rule `INPUT` chain to permit ftp access to some specific destination for all hosts on your network.

In this case a `RETURN` might be a better choice.  Assuming the policy of your INPUT chain is `DROP` this would probably also have the same results.

```
iptables -A IP1 -p tcp --dport 20 -j RETURN
iptables -A IP1 -p tcp --dport 21 -j RETURN
iptables -A IP1 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Should I use RETURN lastly or in the two rules? RETURN goes back to the INPUT chain at the time it is called?

Comment: It kinda depends on the specific needs of your specific rules.  It is probably fine for now to just go with the rules you suggested in your question.  I was mostly just adding this note here for any future people that might find your question and have slightly different requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Your commands look right to me.

`--sport` would be for the source port (the one the client is connecting *from*), which is often randomized.  `--dport` is correct.  Recall that a connection is a 4-tuple of source address, source port, destination address, and destination port - iptables acts on the 4-tuple in the packet it sees.

One interesting thing about FTP is that in passive mode, the client and server agree on a new port number.  Also, I believe the use of port 20 is for a connection *to the file's destination* regardless of which is the server on the control connection, but it can't hurt to block it in this case.